# Archer API to Get User ID not working for all users

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

I am using Archer API LookupUserID to get the ID of a user. This works for users having same domain as I have. When i lookup for a user which is of other domain but exists in application it shows User not found. Can anyone help!

Answer (score 0):

Joy, what version of Archer are you running?

Comment: RSA Version 6.4

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this issue to RSA for review.